# Undefined variable outside of PhoneGap globalization callback

Tags: cordova, callback, scope, globalization

I'm playing around with PhoneGap (Cordova version 2.6.0) currently and my JavaScript knowledge is unfortunately really rudimentarily.
Im trying to use the globalization object of PhoneGap to get the names of the month but I'm not able to get the result out of the callback.

That's the code:

```
<button onclick="getCurrentDate()">Get Current Date</button>

function getCurrentDate(){
  var currentDate = new Date();

  alert(getMonthAsString(currentDate.getMonth()) + ' ' + currentDate.getDate() 
    + ', ' + currentDate.getFullYear());
  }

function getMonthAsString(month){
    var monthString;
    navigator.globalization.getDateNames(
        function(names){
            monthString = names.value[month]; 
            alert(monthString);
         },
         function(){
            alert('Error getting names\n');
         },
         {type:'wide', item:'months'}
      );
      return monthString;
    }
```

The alert has the right month but the return value stays undefined.

Comment: How are you calling this function? What are you testing with? I just tried this on Cordova 2.5 and it worked fine when I did ```<a href="#" onclick=console.log(getMonthAsString(2)); return false;">Test month2</a>```.

Comment: I'm calling this function from another function which is building the whole date string and this function is called by a button. I'll update the initial post

Comment: Weird, your code works fine for me, first it alerted April, then it alerted the full date. What device are you testing with and what browser is installed on that device? What version of Android?

Comment: I'm using an iPhone 6.1 simulator. Just tried it again: The first alert displays the month as string ("April") but the second alert only shows "undefined 19, 2013"...really weird.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to assume you were on Android. This is so weird. Is there any way you can try with a real device? Does the same behavior happen on, say, iPhone 5 simulator? What does it output if you put console.log(monthString) right before the return? What happens if you return monthString right after the alert()? I'm just guessing here...I'll try to crank up an iOS environment this weekend if we still can't get it. I feel like it is either some subtle difference in the browsers, a bug with iOS simulator, or something that I'm going to feel real stupid for missing ;)